# Convert values of two dc motors to angle ( single output)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, dc

I have built a 2WD + caster robot car. The two back wheels are powered by two dc motors.
The steering is done by either turning on both motors to drive straight forward or turning any of them to turn left or right.

I have written a  python code that allows me to drive the robotocar, take pictures and also save in txt files the values of the two motors.

I want to use the donkeycar section for training my model. However, I need to convert the values of the two motors into a single output or angle.
only so can the model learn and train.

How to convert values of two dc motors into a angle?